# keep a websocket php file running

Tags: php, sockets, unix, websocket, server

I have a php file server that runs a websocket chat application.

I need to create two scripts,
one that keeps the server running even after closing the terminal
and the second to check every seconds if the server is still alive.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't have any ideas but Google has a lot of them.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.